# StackedIndex is causing a failed assertion error

Tags: flutter, dart, stream-builder

I am attempting to create an application with a bottom navigation view. I changed the formatting of my StreamBuilder on one of the indexes, ever since I changed that streamBuilder I have been getting a weird error:

> RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#eae01
> relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT
> 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart': Failed assertion: line 1694
> pos 12: 'hasSize'

Also I am getting:

> Failed assertion: line 1697 pos 12: '!_debugDoingThisLayout': is not
> true.

Here are the build and the init I believe are causing the problem:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // TODO: implement initState
    _outerStream = Firestore.instance
        .collection('posts/player/post')
        .orderBy('time', descending: true)
        .snapshots()
        .take(2);

    _innerStream =
        Firestore.instance.collection('posts/player/post').snapshots();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: _outerStream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) return Container(child: Text('Loading...'));
          final int highLightCount = snapshot.data.documents.length;
          return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: _innerStream,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData)
                return Container(child: Text('There are no current posts'));
              return ListView(
                physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                children: getPostItems(snapshot),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

this code is definitely messy right now, but here are the additional methods being used:

```
getPostItems(AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    return snapshot.data.documents.map((doc) => getListItem(doc)).toList();
  }

  Widget getListItem(var doc) {
    getProfUrl(doc);
    getDownUrl(doc);

    VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController;
    _videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network(downUrl)
      ..initialize();
    _videoPlayerController.setLooping(true);
    _videoPlayerController.play();

    if (doc["user"] != widget.auth.getUserId()) {
      print("will show");
      if (doc["type"] == "image") {
        return new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  new MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => new playerViewProfilePageIndex(
                          widget.auth, doc["user"])),
                );
              },
              child: new ListTile(
                title: new Text(doc["title"]),
                subtitle: new Text(doc["description"].toString()),
                leading: new Container(
                  width: 44.0,
                  height: 44.0,
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    image: new DecorationImage(
                        fit: BoxFit.fill, image: NetworkImage(profUrl)),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            new Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(4, 4, 4, 4),
              child: new Center(
                child: new AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: 1 / 1,
                  child: new Container(
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                        image: new DecorationImage(
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      alignment: FractionalOffset.topCenter,
                      image: new NetworkImage(downUrl),
                    )),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      } else {
        return new Column(children: <Widget>[
          new ListTile(
              title: new Text(doc["title"]),
              subtitle: new Text(doc["description"].toString()),
              leading: new Container(
                  width: 44.0,
                  height: 44.0,
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    image: new DecorationImage(
                        fit: BoxFit.fill, image: NetworkImage(profUrl)),
                  ))),
          new Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(4, 4, 4, 4),
            child: new Center(
              child: new AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: 500 / 500,
                child: VideoPlayer(_videoPlayerController),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ]);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I suppose getPostItems(snapshot) is a method that returns a List<Widget>, can you show that code?

Comment: I edited the code into the original question

Comment: yeah I see now, Column Widget always try to expand and fill the whole size of the parent, but the parent(ListView) is waiting for the size of the child so try to use the mainAxisSize property to MainAxisSize.min or wrap it in a sizedBox with a specific size

Comment: Does this occurs since the beggining or you can see at first the text 'Loading..' and 'There are no current posts' ?

Comment: I just attempted both of the solutions with wrapping the column, neither the SizedBox or the MainAxisSize seemed to impact the application. When I initially load the application, it will say loading for a second and then break. It should be attempting to load one pot as of now. EDIT! After taking a closer look, it is successful for the account that can view the current post, but is not successful for the account that has no posts visible. Thank you for your help .

Comment: Thank you very much EdwynZN, I have figured out my problem. I had a check for before the data snapshot came through, however I am filtering out the posts that user creates programmatically, that meant there was a case where there was a snapshot but there also was no posts in the postList. I just had to adds  case where there were posts but they were all owned by the currentUser.

Comment: Oh yeah I see that in the outer if doc["user"] != widget.auth.getUserId() when it's false you never return anything, maybe you should check that at the beginning of the getPostItems and return a sized box in a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getListItem is expecting to return a Widget but when `doc["user"] != widget.auth.getUserId()` is false it never returns a value, maybe adding a dummy  SizedBox.shrink with an else could help

```
Widget getListItem(var doc) {
    getProfUrl(doc);
    getDownUrl(doc);

    VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController;
    _videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network(downUrl)
      ..initialize();
    _videoPlayerController.setLooping(true);
    _videoPlayerController.play();

    if (doc["user"] != widget.auth.getUserId()) {
      print("will show");
      if (doc["type"] == "image") {
        return new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  new MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => new playerViewProfilePageIndex(
                          widget.auth, doc["user"])),
                );
              },
              child: new ListTile(
                title: new Text(doc["title"]),
                subtitle: new Text(doc["description"].toString()),
                leading: new Container(
                  width: 44.0,
                  height: 44.0,
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    image: new DecorationImage(
                        fit: BoxFit.fill, image: NetworkImage(profUrl)),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            new Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(4, 4, 4, 4),
              child: new Center(
                child: new AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: 1 / 1,
                  child: new Container(
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                        image: new DecorationImage(
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      alignment: FractionalOffset.topCenter,
                      image: new NetworkImage(downUrl),
                    )),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      } else {
        return new Column(children: <Widget>[
          new ListTile(
              title: new Text(doc["title"]),
              subtitle: new Text(doc["description"].toString()),
              leading: new Container(
                  width: 44.0,
                  height: 44.0,
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    image: new DecorationImage(
                        fit: BoxFit.fill, image: NetworkImage(profUrl)),
                  ))),
          new Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(4, 4, 4, 4),
            child: new Center(
              child: new AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: 500 / 500,
                child: VideoPlayer(_videoPlayerController),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ]);
      }
    } else return const SizedBox.shrink(); //return a Widget when the if is false
  }
```